# Paste into org-mode: utf-8-unix cannot encode \207 for á, \222 for í

Tags: org-mode, copy-paste

I'm learning emacs (on spacemacs) and focusing on orgmode.

When I paste into an org-mode buffer from a non-english language that contains accents and other signs (in my case italian and spanish) I get:

> These default coding systems were tried to encode text
> In the buffer... :
> utf-8-unix (2291 . 4194183) (2330 . 4194194) (2334 . 4194194) (2353 . 4194194) (2367 . 4194194) (2397 . 4194199) (2400 . 4194240) (2403 . 4194183)
> (2449 . 4194204) (2463 . 4194199) (2519 . 4194198))
> However, each of them encountered characters it couldn't‚be encode:
> utf-8-unix cannot encode these: á í í í í ó ¿ á ú ó ...

Is there a way to convert the characters when pasting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved it (I pasted it in the init part of my spacemacs configuration):

```el
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq erc-server-coding-system '(utf-8 . utf-8))
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
;; Treat clipboard input as UTF-8 string first; compound text next, etc.
(setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))

(setenv "LANG" "fr_FR.UTF-8")
(setenv "LC_ALL" "fr_FR.UTF-8")
```

Comment: FYI: You can accept your own answer.